# MOSFET controlled by optocoupler (PWM) gives wrong ouput

Tags: mosfet, pwm, opto-isolator

My schematic is as follows:

[image]

I control the optocoupler by PWM output from STM32, the output of TLP188 (scope between ground and pin 4) gives me this result which looks ok with 30% duty cycle and 12 V on Vgs (R22 and R23 gives voltage divider by 2).

The output show me 23.7 V instead of 30% of 24 V (8 V). Does Q2 is not a good choice?

Oscillogram:

[image]

Comment: How did you measure 23.7V. Did you connect some load to drain?

Comment: I put 470 Ohms charge resistor

Comment: What happens to the waveform if you put a capacitor across it as well as the resistor? What load (e.g., a motor, an LED,...) will be on the output?

Comment: Show the faulty waveform please.

Comment: How do you measure the output? Maybe you're measuring the amplitude instead of effective voltage, in which case 23.7 would be correct.

Comment: I replaced resistor by a real motor, and measure is now correct. I am not 100% confident in this mosfet that is maybe damage and will try to replace by a new one.

Comment: @Delphes Look at the RMS voltage (7.03 V) in the statistics, not the peak voltage. And I can't see the 23.7 V mentioned in the question anywhere on that image. The MOSFET is working properly.

Comment: The image shows the gate voltage I did not mentioned , sorry.